# Passing the data from View form to Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-binding

I'm trying to create a repository website in ASP.NET Core. I have a web form, which should pass the data to a database.

I think that database connection works, because when I entered "dotnet ef database update" it created a table with columns from my model. In my controller I have a [HttpPost] tag on an action where it should be posted and I also injected a model.

Unfortunately, when I submit a form, I receive an error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13] Connection id "0HLPJH54HAOGK",
>   Request id "0HLPJH54HAOGK:0000000B": An unhandled exception was thrown
>   by the application. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

No data is passed to a Database as well.

Controller:

```
namespace ASP.Controllers
{
    public class ResolutionController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ResolutionContext _context;

        public ResolutionController(ResolutionContext context)
       {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult ShowAll()
        {
            return View(_context.Resolutions.ToList());
        } 

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AddResolution()
        { 
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddResolution(Resolution resolution)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Resolutions.Add(resolution);

                _context.SaveChanges();

                return View("AddResolution");
            }
            return View("ShowAll");
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace ASP.Models
{
    public class ResolutionContext : DbContext
    {
        public ResolutionContext(DbContextOptions<ResolutionContext> options) 
: base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Resolution> Resolutions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Resolution
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ResolutionFilePath { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateOfAdopting { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AddResolution View

```
@model Resolution

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dodaj uchwałę";
}

<div class="section both-sections" >
    <div class="left-side-section">
        dummy
    </div>
    <div id="right-side-section">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <form asp-controller="Resolution" asp-action="AddResolution" 
method="post">
                <h2>Insert Resolution</h2>
                <ul class="add-resolution-list">
                    <li>
                        <label for="name"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="input-fields">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="description"></label>
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Description" class="input-fields">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="date"></label>
                        <input type="date" asp-for="DateOfAdopting" class="input-fields">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="resolution"></label>
                        <input type="file" name="resolution" class="input-fields">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Add Resolution">
                    </li>
                 </ul>
            </form>
         }
     </div>
</div>
```

And the ShowAll Action:

```
@model IEnumerable<Resolution>

<p>ViewResolution</p> 

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<div>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</div>
}
```

I expected it to write data from a form to a Database, but instead I have an error.

Answer (score 0):

`ResolutionContext` is used `ResolutionController` in the constructor.

You should register your Context in the `Startup.cs`
like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<ResolutionContext>(_ => new ResolutionContext (Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

For more info [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-asp-net-core-project)

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate and pass a model into your view:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddResolution()
{
    var myModel = new Resolution();
    myModel.DateOfAdopting = DateTime.Now()  // default value
    return View(myModel);
}
```

EDIT: You also have some typos in your `<input>` definitions where you are using `asp-for` - that is for labels. You need a `name=` attribute for binding `<input>`s:

```
<li>
    <label for="name"></label>
    //  typo 1
    <input type="text" name="Name" class="input-fields">
</li>
<li>
    <label for="description"></label>
    //  typo 2
    <input type="text" name="Description" class="input-fields">
</li>
<li>
    <label for="date"></label>
    //  typo 3
    <input type="date" name="DateOfAdopting" class="input-fields">
</li>
<li>
    <label for="resolution"></label>
    <input type="file" name="resolution" class="input-fields">
</li>
<li>
    <input type="submit" name="submit-button" value="Add Resolution">
</li>
```

Comment: Do not work for now.

I found that we are executing a query into the database, and database itself has a row for each form i submited, but every column contains the value of null. Looks like model binding do not bind the data from a form. Could be something wrong with [HttpPost] method.

Comment: Set a break point at the first line of HttpPost. Is the model populated? If not, are there console errors? Binding seems right.

Comment: Yes, in local variables using debug mode I have a resolution variable, but all it's child variables are still null or random date (01.01.0001 00:00:00)